# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF erreur

Tags: php, html

I looked at many other questions, but I can't find my own answer in it. here is my syntax error (unexpeted T_IF):

```
   if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$Nom=$_POST['Nom'];
$debPeriode=$_POST['debPeriode'];
$deb=$_POST['deb'];
$finPeriode=$_POST['finPeriode'];
$fin=$_POST['fin'];
$Detail=$_POST['Detail'];
$Periode=$deb_Periode.$deb."-".$fin_Periode.$fin
 //création de la requête SQL:
if (empty($Nom)||empty($Periode)||empty($Detail))
```

So please help me

Comment: Missing semicolon on `$Periode=$deb_Periode.$deb."-".$fin_Periode.$fin`

Comment: See also [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a missing semi-colon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$Periode=$deb_Periode.$deb."-".$fin_Periode.$fin;
                                                ^
```